# Possible to have different taskbars on different windows 10 desktops?

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, virtual-desktop

When creating different desktops in Windows 10 (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) it seems you can only have one taskbar across all desktops.

Ideally, I want to have a personal desktop and a work one which have different items pinned to taskbar.

Is it possible to configure the virtual desktops in Windows 10 to have different taskbars?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the same task bar, yes.  And you cannot natively have radically different task bars.

It may be possible, for apps with multiple instance capabilities to have one icon on a desktop for one instance and another icon on a different desktop for the other instance.

Practically speaking, the answer to your question is no, you cannot have different task bars on different desktops, at least not natively within Windows 10 up to V 20H2.

Comment: Any hope for Windows 11? Did they finally add the feature? I'd like each taskbar to have a different color! I forget which Desktop I'm on at times.

Comment: I do not think so. Windows 11 is more restrictive than Windows 10.

Answer (score 5):

Go to multitasking in system and the virtual desktops then select 'only the desktop I am using" in 'on the taskbar, show window that are open on'

Comment: This does not address the question.    I wanted to have items pinned to the start menu so I could launch them and have shortcuts setup for work / home / .... on different desktops.
This simply limits which items appear in the taskbar once opened